# How to access to "Access Token page" in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need help to get into this "Access Token page" in GCP. It can't be found at the moment. It is really helpful for me to find out it. If it doesn't, tell me another way to remove the authentication token when deploying a ML model in GCP.

[This is the screenshot of page I wants to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIbyX.png)

Comment: I have never seen that page. What is the service name and URL?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [Access Token page](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Access-Tokens-Page_145281436) is a Dataprep feature that can be accessed through the settings inside the Dataprep UI. It is not a global GCP feature and not applicable to your case.

Secondly, I assume you are talking about deploying a ML model like in AI Platform [Deploying Models](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models). As it states [there](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#service-account), when deploying the model you either specify a service account (if using a custom prediction routine) or use the one [automatically given by Google](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#google-managed). In both cases it includes the service account [token creation role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#token-creator-role) which creates [OAuth2 access tokens](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth) that last only 1 hour.

For prediction you just need to use a service account with the permissions shown in [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/access-control#permissions_needed_for_prediction).